# "I can not able to" Sentence formation

Tags: meaning-in-context

> I can not able to understand

Is the above sentence grammatically correct?

The words **can** and **able** have the same meaning, they're both used to talk about the ability of a person. How do I correctly use each word in a sentence?

Comment: No, it's not correct because `can` requires a verb, and `able` isn't one

Comment: @bigt I would have put your comment as an answer, you've done a good job giving a simple but complete explanation.

Answer (score 3):

No, the sentence formation is incorrect.

**"Can"** is used in the **present tense**. It is used to talk about our ability to do things.

> **Example:**
>
> She can speak English well.

**"Able to"** is also possible in these cases; However, it sounds a bit more formal here.

> **Example:**
>
> She is able to speak English well.

So, you can say "I am not able to understand." This might be a right one.

Comment: Hi Ramya, I think your question could be improved by including a direct "yes" or "no" to the question "Is the above sentence formation is correct?" :)

Comment: No, the above sentence formation is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks, I think you should put that in the text of your answer to make it better!

Comment: Mark, I have edited my answer as you said.

Comment: Great work, I've upvoted it :)

Comment: You could also say "I can not understand".